# How to edit the Workflow initiated email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, workflow2013

I always get the workflow initiated whenever I submit a form in a list but it gives wrong information about the change number.
Can I know how can I edit this Workflow initiated email in SharePoint Designer 2013. I don't seem to find the workflow initiated workflow anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This workflow was created by me long ago and realized that it wasn't showing in the SharePoint Designer 2013 and neither in the normal workflows. Rather I had to go to the List workflows and found the workflow there and removed it and it worked perfectly. I hope it will help someone who will be confused.

Comment: don't forget to "accept" your own answer so that future seekers see i marked as answered.

Comment: Hi @Willman. I will do once it reaches 2 days marks. Thanks.